# How can I configure WebStorm to recognize component bindings?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

WebStorm correctly recognizes angular components, but it consistently highlights the component bindings as invalid attributes. Is this just a WebStorm quirk or could there be something missing in my configuration?

Comment: I have the same problem. They cannot pick $ctrl, nor controllerAs.

Comment: I think it's not supported yet and the issue is reported a long time ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20339. Angular2 is interpreted correctly though